# How to create mysql users and database during deployment of mysql in kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, deployment, openshift

I wanted to create some mysql users and databases while creating mysql deployment in kubernetes.
means when mysql deployment is being created its shouldalso create some users as well as database in the mysql.

Below is the deployment config i have created for mysql. let me know is it possible to add here some data which will create the user and database.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30081
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mysql-config
                key: mysql_root_password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      - image: phpmyadmin:5
        name: phpmyadmin
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: password
          - name: PMA_HOST
            value: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) (under "Initializing a fresh instance"): you can use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as a point to which to volume mount scripts and SQL files for database initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `postStart` of [Container Lifecycle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/). It makes you run additional SQL or script after starting your mysql container.

For instance, if you create your own script `create_user.sh` that is executed some DDL like `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` through `mysql` command, then you can configure it as follows.

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/path/to/create_users.sh"]
```

Refer [Attach Handlers to Container Lifecycle Events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) for more configuration details.

Comment: From the documentation `This hook is executed immediately after a container is created. However, there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT. No parameters are passed to the handler.` mysql may not have even started yet so any attempt to affect the daemon may fail.